# How to use IN operator with variable number of parameters?

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I have a dataset connection to an MS Access database.

I want to use IN operator in WHERE clause like:

```
WHERE DepartmentID IN (1,2,3)
```

This means that all record with an ID of 1, 2 and 3 will be filtered. But the problem is I cannot create a parameter like:

```
WHERE DepartmentID IN (?)
```

It only works with WHERE DepartmentID IN (?,?,?). This is okay but the parameter should not limit only to 3 parameter.

A value in IN operator could be 1 or more value.

How to do this in VB.NET?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/337792/284240

Comment: I am pretty sure this is a duplicate (but not of the one currently linked ... this is much more language-specific). In any case, the trick is to generate the `(?,...?)` dynamically based on the *count* of parameters (do not put in any data here!) and then to add the same number of parameters to the query. (This is both extensible and prevents injection attacks.)

Comment: [Look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause), second answer it is really like the solution suggested by @pst.

Comment: @DanAndrews Find a duplicate SO question using it? :) Then we could close this question legitimately.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate since I am asking for ms access as the database.

Answer (score 1):

The IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause.

SQL IN Syntax

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (@value1,@value2,...)
```

You can do a loop instead but you will be prone to SQL injection

Comment: -1 You **can**  use the in operator to just pass one value. Apart from that you don't explain how  to parametrize a `IN` clause in VB.NET.

Comment: Why is a loop _prone to SQL-Injection_? You're open to SQL injection only if you don't use parameters and not if you're building these parameters programmatically(f.e. in a loop).

Comment: It will be tricky..The parameter in IN clause he is asking are not fixed it could be 10 , 5 , or 2.. I my case I cannot think a way to generate parameters.